# Preventing ASP.Net projects from copying {assembly}.dll.config to bin folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, web-config

When building ASP.Net projects in Visual Studio (version 2015 Community), website configuration files (*e.g.*, `Web.Config`) are copied by the build process into the `bin` folder alongside the compiled .dll file, and renamed  `{assembly}.dll.config`.

This occurs despite the *Properties Window* for the Web.config file being set with the following parameters:

[image: Web.config Properties Window]

For our solution, this second copy of the file is not necessary, nor used in the `{assembly}.dll.config` form found in the output `bin` folder.

**I would like to know what is necessary to prevent Visual Studio from making a copy of the configuration file and placing it in the `bin` output directory.**

Having sensitive configuration settings in *two* places (`Web.config` in the root directory, and `{assembly}.dll.config` in the output directory) is problematic from a security standpoint.

Comment: How do you expect your program to run if your `Web.config` isn't in the bin directory? Do you expect your compiled application and IIS to just magically know the values in that file in your local development folder?

Comment: In a setup where security is a concern, you shouldn't have production / sensitive data in your `Web.config` at all. It means that any other contributes to the code will also have access to a production database connection string etc. which is not necessary or desirable. `Web.config` in your development directory (and bin) should should point to test data and test databases. When you deploy your app to a production server, these values should be updated to the sensitive production values.

Comment: @caesey I am looking to eliminate the redundant {assembly}.dll.config file, not the Web.config file that is actually used.  Sorry if that was confusing.  Web.config is indeed necessary.  A separate {assembly}.dll.config is not.

Comment: @caesay All data is encrypted in our configuration files, and there is nothing useful in them for attackers.  We rely on Web.config for server installation configuration and business client customization. Our security concern is that these settings are more difficult to isolate between deployments if we have to change them in 2 places or remember to delete the redundant copy.

Comment: @caesay, Web.config is already copied to root of project. Deleting the file from bin folder has no effect on the final outcome, thus I don't think it is even necessary for that file to be there.

Answer (score 2):

- To *deploy* your app, `Publish` your application. This way, only the necessary assemblies/files are deployed. Your **published** `/bin` folder will reflect this (will not have the "duplicates" you mention).
- Security: depending on what you're after, you can

  - separate "sensitive" information from `web.confg` into their own files. This usually is only for keeping such from online repositories (`TFS`, `Git`, etc.) - by *excluding* the file from being in source control

    e.g.

    ```
    <appSettings file="AllMySecrets.config">
    ....
    ```
  - Use [encryption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx)

Hth.

Comment: While using publish is a less ideal solution for us, separating the configuration settings into a different file is a viable solution.  Upvoting in that this will work in the scenario that the `{assembly}.dll.config` duplicating behavior cannot be somehow disabled.